# How to create folder on Google Drive from Android Service using Google API Client?

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

How can I create folder on Google Drive from Android Service using `GoogleAPIClient`?

Comment: refer this   https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/demo.